# Negative angle values using CABasicAnimation

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, transform, cabasicanimation

I'm rotating continuously an `UIImageView` using `CABasicAnimation` using the following code:

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:M_PI * 2];
fullRotation.duration = 6;
fullRotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VAL;
[self.myImageView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

The animation works as expected, but when I log the rotation angle it goes from `0` to `180` and then from `-180` to `0`. I would expect it to go from `0` to `360` and then back to `0`.

I'm using the following code to get the rotation angle:

```
CGFloat radians = [[self.myImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue];

CGFloat degrees = (radians * (180 / M_PI));

NSLog(@"ROTATION = %f", radians);
```

Answer (score 0):

A rotation angle is uniquely determined only up to multiples of 360 degrees (or 2*π radians), for example -90 and 270 degrees describe exactly the same rotation.

```
[[self.myImageView valueForKeyPath:@"layer.presentationLayer.transform.rotation.z"] floatValue]
```

gives the rotation of the image view at a particular point in time, and that rotation 
can be described using an angle between 0 and 2*π (as you expect) or using an angle
between -π and π (which is what actually happens).

To normalize an arbitrary angle into the range `0 <= degrees < 360`
you can do

```
degrees = fmod(degrees, 360.0);
if (degrees < 0) degrees += 360.0;
```

Comment: So...is there any way of getting the angle from 0 to 360? Or do I have to map the negative values manually?

Comment: @guardabrazo: If you need it in the range 0 .. 360 then you should map: `if (degrees < 0) degrees += 360.0;`